# Strict or not strict

Tags: javascript

I have this file, which is reduced in size, but clearly illustrates my question:

```
'use strict';

let _ = require('lodash');
let secret;


let Ejs = function () {
    'use strict';

    this.engine = require('ejs');
    this.fs = require('fs');
};

Ejs.prototype.generate = function (config) {
    'use strict';

    let template;

    template = this.engine.compile(this.fs.readFileSync(config.src, 'utf8'));

    ...
};

module.exports = new Ejs();
```

Do I need to use 'use strict' in expression and prototype, or on top of the file is sufficient? Or I need to have all three of them?

Comment: The first one already defines "use strict" globally, no need to repeat it in other functions in the file.

Comment: Strict Mode is a new feature in ECMAScript 5 that allows you to place a program, or a function, in a "strict" operating context. This strict context prevents certain actions from being taken and throws more exceptions.
only one strict which is on the top is enough no need to add inside other methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you have defined `use strict` at the top of the file then no need to add inside other methods.

For more information about `use strict` please check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

Hope this may help you to understand.